# Where does Eclipse store the info about which workspace to start up with?

Tags: eclipse

When I launch Eclipse it starts with one of the workspaces I created and selected "don't ask again" (standardly, Eclipse asks about which workspace to start with during the startup).

So it must store somewhere which workspace to use. Where does it store this piece of information?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In

`$HOME/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_3.7.0_155965261/configuration/.settings`

there is a file

`org.eclipse.ui.ide.prefs`

where it is stored.

Comment: As of 2014 (Eclipse Luna release), this answer is no longer correct. See @JStevenPerry 's answer below for the new location.

Comment: @E-Riz this is the correct directory (Ubuntu, Eclipse 2019-12 4.14.0). Sure it will change with the next version of eclipse (mine is at `4.14.0_1473617060` ) but the path _structure_ remains the same. On the other hand I installed from `tar.gz` and I don't have an `$ECLIPSE_HOME` defined.

Answer (score 15):

With Eclipse Juno, I can see this information in:
`eclipse\configuration\.settings` file.

I guess you are looking for `RECENT_WORKSPACES` and `SHOW_WORKSPACE_SELECTION_DIALOG` vars.

Answer (score 15):

The settings have changed since this question was posted, as newer versions of Eclipse have been released.

**With Eclipse Luna**, navigate to `$ECLIPSE_HOME/eclipse/configuration/.settings` and the file `org.eclipse.ui.ide.prefs` contains settings like this (**Windows file configuration shown**):

```
MAX_RECENT_WORKSPACES=5
RECENT_WORKSPACES=C\:\\src\\eclipse-workspaces\\luna\\MyApp\nC\:\\src\\eclipse-workspaces\\luna\\MyOtherApp
RECENT_WORKSPACES_PROTOCOL=3
SHOW_WORKSPACE_SELECTION_DIALOG=true
eclipse.preferences.version=1
```

Each entry in `RECENT_WORKSPACES` appears to be delimited by `\n` with no spaces. Whenever I manually shuffle my workspaces around (which is rare, but it happens), I've had great success hand-editing this file, saving it, and having the new paths show up just fine in the Workspace Lancher/Select a Workspace dialog.

Comment: Is this also the case for Eclipse Neon? I'd like to copy my existing list of recent workspaces, but I can't find the Neon file to copy to.

Comment: Never mind, I think I found it! :) 
In Eclipse Neon, it looks like the full path is now:
`/home/$USER/eclipse/java-neon/eclipse/configuration/.settings/org.eclipse.ui.ide.prefs`

Comment: Looks like this is still true for Eclipse Oxygen (tested with eclipse-jee-oxygen-1a-win32-x86_64).

Answer (score 2):

You have eclipse configuration files in "eclipse_home"/configuration and the one you may looking for is in settings directory : org.eclipse.ui.ide.prefs

Answer (score 0):

I was facing an issue with Spring Tool Suite 4. The workspace used to give an error and I wasn't able to select other workspace also. With the help of some answers already given, I could locate the configuration in $ECLIPSE_HOME\sts-4.7.1.RELEASE\configuration.settings\org.eclipse.epp.mpc.ui.prefs

I removed RECENT_WORKSPACES property (after you try to restart, it adds default entry again) and changed

```
SHOW_WORKSPACE_SELECTION_DIALOG=true
```

STS started showing workspace selection dialog again.

Answer (score -1):

If Eclipse has been installed with **ubuntu-make**, the file location is `~/.local/share/umake/ide/eclipse-jee/configuration/.settings/org.eclipse.ui.ide.prefs`.