# Where does ARM Development Studio IDE (Eclipse) saves the last workspace path

Tags: eclipse, arm, eclipse-cdt

We use ARM Development Studio v2019. The IDE is Eclipse CDT based. I am trying to find out where it saves the path for the last workspace used.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12385413/274579), but the info is either outdated or not applicable to ARM DS.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26550841/2670892) to the linked question is still the current location for these settings.

Answer (score 0):

Searching the `org.eclipse.ui.ide.prefs` file mentioned in the linked question, on my Win10 machine, using the ARM DS 2019, the file is located at:

`C:\Users\XYZ\AppData\Roaming\ARM\ds\2019.a-1\eclipse\configuration\.settings\org.eclipse.ui.ide.prefs`